# Proof of the conjugate commutator identity $ [g, h]^s = [g^s, h^s]. $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

One of the five [well-known commutator identities](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/on-five-wellknown-commutator-identities/D7D2D9BFC76938E1AFF1AD3CF88BF021), also found [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup#Commutators), and apparently true for any elements $s, g, h$ of a group G, is as follows:

$$ [g, h]^s = [g^s, h^s]. $$

I have failed to prove it and wonder where I have gone wrong in my proof. I also wonder where I should be looking to find proofs of this kind of elementary result, neither proofwiki nor Dummit&Foote, my usual places, seem to cover this.

---

Attempted proof:

(EDIT: in the comments it was pointed out where this goes wrong, this identity is indeed easy to prove! Though I am still curious where to find proofs of simple identities like this)

$$ \begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
   {[}g, h]^s & = (g^{-1}h^{-1}gh)^s \\
            & = s^{-1}g^{-1}h^{-1}ghs
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
$$

$$ \begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
   {[}g^s, h^s] & = (g^s)^{-1}(h^s)^{-1}(g^s)(h^s) \\
                & = (s^{-1}gs)^{-1}(s^{-1}hs)^{-1}(s^{-1}gs)(s^{-1}hs) \\
                & = sg^{-1}s^{-1}sh^{-1}s^{-1}s^{-1}gss^{-1}hs \\
                & = sg^{-1}h^{-1} s^{-1}s^{-1} ghs
 \end{aligned}\end{equation}
$$

Comment: Are you sure $s \in G$? Normally, when we take $g \in G$ and talk about $g^s$ we have $s \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $g^s$ mean multiplying $g$ together $s$ times (with negative $s$ meaning multiplying the inverse of $g$).

Comment: Good to check but I am sure! Both sources define the operation of conjugation: $g^s = s^{-1}gs$. Actually, both define it slightly differently, here I have used the definition from wikipedia which matches the definition D&F uses.

Comment: $(s^{-1}gs)^{-1}=s^{-1}g^{-1}(s^{-1})^{-1}=s^{-1}g^{-1}s$, not $sgs^{-1}$.  Otherwise conjugation would not be a group homomorphism!

Comment: I am quite embarrassed, that was exactly the problem @user10354138, and now it is easy to prove. Thank you!

Comment: @roundsquare $x^g$ for group elements $x$ and $g$ is very common notation, as is ${}^gx$. $x^g=g^{-1}xg$ and ${}^gx = gxg^{-1}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ah... good to know. I suppose I should send in a complaint to the Department of Abstract Algebra but I doubt they'd change notation for or me :)

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments, the inverse of $ab$ is not $a^{-1}b^{-1}$, but rather $b^{-1}a^{-1}$. Thus:

$$\begin{align}
[g^s, h^s] &= [s^{-1}gs, s^{-1}hs] \\
&= (s^{-1}gs)^{-1}(s^{-1}hs)^{-1}(s^{-1}gs)(s^{-1}hs)\\
&=(s^{-1}g^{-1}s)(s^{-1}h^{-1}s)(s^{-1}gs)(s^{-1}hs) \\
&= s^{-1}g^{-1}h^{-1}ghs \\
&= [g, h]^s
\end{align}$$
The reason why such an identity exists is precisely because the conjugation map $G \to G$ given by $g \mapsto g^s$ is a group homomorphism. More generally, one can prove that for any group homomorphism $\varphi: G \to H$ and elements $a, b \in G$, one has $\varphi([a, b]) = [\varphi(a), \varphi(b)]$.

Comment: The more general statement is the best approach here, because (1) the proof of it requires no idea at all, it works automatically (you just use the definition of the homomorphism property and the commutator, and *tada* you are done), (2) the statement can be applied in many other settings as well, (3) the fact that conjugation is a homomorphism is also useful in other contexts.